# jquery : Unbind to specific elements

Tags: jquery

I disabled enter key in my application using the below code,

```
$(document).bind("keydown", disableEnter);
function disableEnter(e) { if (e.which == 13) e.preventDefault(); }
```

the above code is working fine, as the enter key is not allowed throughout the application.

Now, I would like to enable enter key for specific textarea inputs,

I tried the below code,

```
$(document).not('textarea').bind("keydown", disableEnter);
```

But, its not working. Any suggestions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function disableEnter(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && $(e.target).is(':not(textarea)')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hMW7S/)

Comment: Using this same code, if you need to dynamically select which elements to enable enter, just replace ':not(textarea)' with ':not(.allowenter)' and set class 'allowenter' on the elements for which you would like to enable enter key